# View component not rendering properly through AJAX

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I've built a site where users can alter various types of data through multiple view components. When I call these view components on initial page load everything works fine. However when I try refreshing a view component through an ajax call, any lists in those view components repeat a single element multiple times, and my jquery functions stop working.

Here is my main view:

```
@model ContractModel
@using Portal.ViewComponents

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Contract View";
}

...

<div id="ResultModel_Scope_Facplan">
   @await Component.InvokeAsync("ContractPart", new { contractPartName = "Model_Scope_Facplan", projectName = Model.ProjectName })
</div>
```

My ajax:

```
@section Scripts {

    <script>
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });


                $(".PartialButton").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var ElementID = event.target.id.split("-");
            var contractPart = ElementID[0];
            var contractAction = ElementID[1];
            var actionValue = ElementID[2];
            console.log($("#Form" + contractPart + actionValue).serialize() + "&ProjectName=@(Model.ProjectName)&contractAction=" + contractAction);
            console.log(ElementID);
            $.ajax({
                url: "@(Url.Action(""))/" + contractPart,
                type: "POST",
                data: $("#Form" + contractPart + actionValue).serialize()+"&ProjectName=@(Model.ProjectName)&contractAction=" + contractAction,
                success: function (data) {
                    //Fill div with results
                    alert(data);
                    //debugger;
                    $("#Result" + contractPart).html(data);
                },
                error: failedSearch(contractPart)
            });
        });


        function failedSearch(ElementID) {
           // alert(ElementID + " failed!");
          //  $("#Result"+ElementID).html = "There was a problem in the search. Please try again later.";
        }
    </script>
}
```

My actual view component invoke is pretty simple (just sends the right data to the right view).

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke(string contractPartName, string projectName)
{
    return View(contractPartName, FindContractPart(contractPartName, projectName));

}
```

And the view component template:

```
@model IEnumerable<Model_Scope_Facplan>

@if (@Model != null)
{
    <div class="row">
        Care Provider &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Payer

    </div>

                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <form id="FormModel_Scope_Facplan@(i)" action="">
                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <input asp-for=@Model.ElementAt(i).CareProviderID class="form-control" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <input asp-for=@Model.ElementAt(i).PayerID  class="form-control" />
                                </div>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus DeleteItem PartialButton" style="color:blue;" id="Model_Scope_Facplan-Delete-@(i)"></span>
                        </div>
                   </form>
                   <br/>
                }
    <form id="FormModel_Scope_Facplan@(Model.Count())" action="">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input name=CareProviderID class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input name=PayerID class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus AddItem PartialButton" style="color:blue;" id="Model_Scope_Facplan-Create-@(Model.Count())"></span>

        </div>
    </form>
}
```

The viewcomponent is returning the correct view template, and in debugging I can see that the ViewComponentResult.ViewData.Model includes the appropriate entries in the list. However the page updated after the ajax call includes only a single element over and over. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like my for loop in the view was breaking - I'm guessing the ElementAt(i) function didn't work after the ajax call for some reason. I ended up switching to a foreach loop and now everything works.

Comment: besides, using `foreach` has advantage that any time you need `i`th element you don't have to iterate `IEnumerable` again. You are doing it twice in the example.